# Button Onclick event not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, onclick

Following is the code of my button in visual studio. I have used other buttons too in the same page but only this is not working. Why?

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSeeCrop" runat="server" Text="See My Crops" BackColor="#1FAC4A" 
        Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#006600" Height="40px" ToolTip="See My Crops" 
        Width="106px" BorderColor="#006600"  OnClientClick="return SeeCrop();" OnClick="btnSeeCrop_Click"/>
```

Code:

```
protected void btnSeeCrop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: Need to set the `OnClientClick` method (whatever `SeeCrop()` is).

Comment: That is already set and is working correctly.

Comment: Is `SeeCrop()` in the client-side code preventing the button from posting to the server?  Perhaps by returning `false`?

Comment: May be! SeeCrop is a JavaScript function.

Comment: @AayushiJain sorry, I meant "see". We need to *see* that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check what your javascript `SeeCrop()` is returning.

If this is returning false it will not submit and stop your button from posting back to the server.

Comment: Yes, it was returning false. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Put a breakpoint on the rule:

```
protected void btnSeeCrop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

And see if your EventHandler is being called, when you click on the button.